# JavaScript: ΔURL, Refresh

Tags: javascript, url, browser

Can someone help me write a JavaScript that, when used, would take any given URL in the browser's URL field and append something to it after the ".com" and before anything else that follows.

Specifically, if I were on http://www.example.com/test, then I would want something to be added, say var.ia.bles to be appended in between the ".com" and "/test" such that it looks like this: http://www.example.com.var.ia.bles/test.

At the end of this task, it would be nice to be able to refresh the browser in such a way it now directs the end user to the path the modified URL points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object has all the pieces you need.

```
location.assign(location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '.var.ia.bles' + location.pathname + location.search + location.hash);
```

Comment: Hey--thanks a lot! Okay, I guess I forgot to mention this in the question, but how would this code come out if you were to make it a bookmarklet. If not, I was thinking of just using Gruber's JavaScript Bookmarklet Builder http://daringfireball.net/2007/03/javascript_bookmarklet_builder.

Comment: To answer my own question: javascript:location.assign(location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+'.ezp-prod1.hul.harvard.edu'+location.pathname+location.search+location.hash);